In authorization code, how to handle shared ownership?
Using AuthorizationCode, how could you handle a co-ownership situation?
Example: you have a SaaS product where users can manage their Stuff™. Alice has her Stuff1 and Stuff2. Later, Alice hires Bob. Alice gives Bob co-ownership of Stuff1 and Stuff2.
You then build an Oauth2 AuthorizationCode platform, allowing third parties to create API integrations.
Bob uses one of those integrations and delegates Stuff1 to SuperReportingIntegration. Naively, I would generate an authcode representing SuperReportingIntegration X Bob = Stuff1. But if Alice later wants to delegate Stuff2, we would have another code representing SuperReportingIntegration X Alice = Stuff2.
But this seems messy: both Alice, Bob, and the 3rd Party, want to have a unified delegation of Stuff1 and Stuff2. But they end up with a split code delegation.
A naive way to handle this would be to implicitly revoke Bob's Stuff1 delegation when Alice delegates Stuff2, and add Stuff1 to it, leaving only: SuperReportingIntegration X Alice = Stuff1+Stuff2.

Would that be an acceptable setup?
Or is AuthCode not suited for this?
Or should we have a higher-level entity (the "team"?) doing the actual delegation?


The solution probably depends on whether you want to grant user-level or company-level access. Here are two common flows.
USER LEVEL ACCESS
The authorization code flow is used with user-level resources:

A user like Bob runs a third-party client.
Bob authenticates and then consents to grant the client particular scopes like SuperReportingIntegration.
The third-party gets an access token containing that scope and Bob's user identity.
The third-party calls your APIs with that access token.
Your API authorization restricts access to Bob's resources (Stuff) for the SuperReportingIntegration business area.

If multiple users run such a client they would all grant access, to create independent delegations. The API access would usually be different depending on which user runs the client.
COMPANY LEVEL ACCESS
In some B2B use cases, the third-party access is fixed and does not depend on a particular user like Bob or Alice. In some cases, Bob or Alice may not even have access to a third-party client. You might then use the client credentials flow to grant third party access:

An administrator (Bob or Alice perhaps) creates an OAuth client for a third party API that acts as a client to your API.
The third-party client is given a client_id and a client credential.
The third-party client gets an access token containing a SuperReportingIntegration scope and a particular tenant ID.
The third-party client calls your APIs with that access token.
Your API authorization restricts access to the tenant's resources (Stuff) for the SuperReportingIntegration business area.


Thank you for your response.
Client credentials seem good if a company wants to access its data. But having a client generate a client-id/client-credentials to then give it to a 3rd party seems insecure, no?
It also means that, as a platform owner, we would not be able to understand which client is using the API for their own usage and which have in fact given a set of credentials to any random 3rd party.

In my answer the client is the third party, which would be assigned credentials by the data owner - which is you I assume. For you to grant any kind of client access you would need to have some kind of trust relationship with them, so that you have confidence that they will look after the client credentials correctly.
